# Address of C++ local variable is before the address returned by gdb info frame locals

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, x86-64, stack-frame

I have the following source code (in a file named vuln.cpp) in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char real[20];
    char pass[20] = "dddddddddddddddd";

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage:\t%s\tpassword\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    memcpy(real, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]) + 1);

    if(strncmp(real, pass, 20) == 0)
    {
        printf("SUCCESS!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("FAILURE!\n");
    }

    printf("real:\t%s\npass:\t%s", real, pass);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the source code using `gcc -g -O0 vuln.cpp`. Note that my machine as well as OS (Ubuntu 18.04) has x86_64 architecture

I ran `gdb a.out`, then `b 16`, then `run $(python -c 'print("a"*10)')`

Now with the code running at line 16, just after the memcpy, I do `info frame`. This outputs

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7fffffffd9d0:
 rip = 0x555555554887 in main (vuln.cpp:17); saved rip = 0x7ffff7a05b97
 source language c++.
 Arglist at 0x7fffffffd9c0, args: argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdaa8
 Locals at 0x7fffffffd9c0, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffd9d0
 Saved registers:
  rbp at 0x7fffffffd9c0, rip at 0x7fffffffd9c8
```

Now I did `p &real`

```
$3 = (char (*)[20]) 0x7fffffffd980
```

How can the address of the local variable `real[0]` be before the address of locals listed in the info frame?

Comment: On x86 stack grows towards numerically lower addresses. Is this the information you are looking for?

Comment: Ah yes, now I understand. But now upon doing p &pass, I see that the address of pass is after address of real, even if pass is declared after real. Shouldn't the compiler allocate the memory on the stack in decreasing order?

Comment: The order of local variables on the stack is at the whim of the compiler. They don't need to be in any particular order. (They will be _constructed_ in the order they are declared, but there is nothing that requires a variable declared earlier to have a lower or higher memory address.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's caused by misunderstanding.